# How i get the window object in node webkit after startup

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I want to register events on the window object just after startup in node-webkits node-main file. If do

```
window.alert("foo")
```

at the beginning i get window not defined. If i wait a few seconds it's working.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.alert("foo")
},2000)
```

Is there another event (maybe member of process) i can listen to, to get notified that the window object is available ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a [loaded](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window#loaded) event emitted that you can hook into.

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();
win.on('loaded', function() {
    // do stuff 
});
```

Comment: In the node-main script this is not working. The window object is not defined at the beginning. And the nw.gui ist only there via window.require("nw.gui").

Comment: read my example and do exactly as it says and you will be fine... I did not write `window.require("nw.gui")` !!!

Comment: documentation says that node-main does not allow you to require gui as there is no gui in that node context.

Comment: 'nw.gui' is not part of node, I am not sure where you are trying to 'require' it from. This module is part of the node-webkit so it is only logical to use it within that context... you should only be able to access it from within a web interface of the webkit, specifically an html document you point to as its 'main' in package config file of the webkit process.

Comment: The question specified that they wanted to perform the alert from the context of the node-main file (javascript node context), not the main file (which is a html file)

Answer (score 0):

The global variable `process` is available from scripts in your HTML page and also from the node-main and bg-script files.

`process` is also an instance of [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html). As a result you can register and event listener in your node-main file and trigger the events from the HTML file on load.

In node-main.js

```
process.on('foo-event', function (win) {
    win.alert('foo');
});
```

In index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            process.emit('foo-event', window);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```